# Combine 2 mysql tables in third table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables in mySql==> tableA, tableB, tableC

In tableA, I have the following

```
+---------+----+----+--------+------------+--+
|  Name   | N1 | N2 | Color  |   State    |  |
+---------+----+----+--------+------------+--+
| John    | 60 | 50 | Red    | Newyork    |  |
| Tom     | 70 | 60 | Green  | Kansas     |  |
| Mathew  | 50 | 40 | Blue   | Texas      |  |
| James   | 40 | 30 | Yellow | Texas      |  |
| SSS     | 70 | 60 | Pink   | Washington |  |
+---------+----+----+--------+------------+--+
```

In tableB, I have the following

```
+--------+----+----+
| S.Name | N3 | N4 |
+--------+----+----+
| Carl   | 10 | 18 |
| Jason  | 15 |  9 |
| Cindy  | 13 | 12 |
| Tim    |  7 | 18 |
| Pam    | 15 | 14 |
+--------+----+----+
```

In table C, I want the following

```
+---------+----+----+--------+------------+--------+
|  Name   | N1 | N2 | Color  |   State    | S.Name |
+---------+----+----+--------+------------+--------+
| John    | 60 | 50 | Red    | Newyork    |        |
| Tom     | 70 | 60 | Green  | Kansas     |        |
| Mathew  | 50 | 40 | Blue   | Texas      |        |
| James   | 40 | 30 | Yellow | Texas      |        |
| SSS     | 70 | 60 | Pink   | Washington |        |
|         | 10 | 18 |        |            | Carl   |
|         | 15 |  9 |        |            | Jason  |
|         | 13 | 12 |        |            | Cindy  |
|         |  7 | 18 |        |            | Tim    |
|         | 15 | 14 |        |            | Pam    |
+---------+----+----+--------+------------+--------+
```

Please help me with this sql query. Thanks

Comment: You should use a View for this.

Comment: may I know the purpose why do you have to store it to the 3rd table ?

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen Why?

Comment: @Strawberry becuase it is useless to store it in a third table unless you want to archive the other tables. With a view you can create a 'virtual' table which you can call.

Comment: @LuudvanKeulen So why bother with a view? Why not simply execute a query?

Comment: @Strawberry to keep your query clean. He didn't mention any code so unless he wants to copy+paste the query he might aswell put it in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two table  as mention above
   When we run the code

```
Create table tablc as
select name,n1,n2,color,State,' ' as sname FROM tablea
union 
select '' as name,n3,n4,'' as color ,'' as State ,'s.name' as sname from tableb
```

the new table will create[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yatC6.png)

the output will display as table tablc

Answer (score 3):

As select result, you can use simple `union all`:

```
select Name as Name, N1 as N1, N2 as N2, Color as Color, State as State, null as S_Name from tableA
union all
select null as Name, N3 as N1, N4 as N2,  null as Color,  null as State, S_Name as S_Name from tableB
```

Comment: I ran the query and I can see the database however when i refresh the table, data disappears...not sure whats happening?

Comment: @ShahidShabbir - This is just `select` query, this not stores result nowhere. you need store  result into another table ?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, it was an insert statement that needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is just call it by using union all

```
select name, n1, n2, color, state, null as 's_name' as recordtype from tablea
union all
select null as 'name', n3 as 'n1', n4 as 'n2', null as 'color', null as 
'state', s_name from tableb
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table tablc as
select name,n1,n2,color,State,' ' as sname FROM tablea
union 
select '' as name,n3,n4,'' as color ,'' as State ,'s.name' as sname from tableb
```

Comment: I ran the query and I can see the database however when i refresh the table, data disappears...not sure whats happening?